# Pulling the top 10 values out of a tree in Java

Tags: java, tree

I am working on a Java program which involves a tree structure and have been struggling with one particular method for some time now. The method is supposed to search the whole tree and find the 10 names with the highest counts. I've been attempting this by using an if statement which essentially says "if its lower than the last maximum but higher than any other value, print it". The problem is that my method is just printing the most popular name 10 times instead of printing the 10 most popular names. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
public static void mostPopularNameTree(){
    popular(root,new Name("-1",'G',-1,-1),0);
}

private static void popular(Node local, Name prev, int i){

    Name current = local.data;  
    int max = 0;

    while(i<10){

        if(current.getCount()<prev.getCount() && current.getCount()>max){
            max = current.getCount();
            prev = current;

            if(local.left != null){
                popular(local.left, prev, i);
            }

            if(local.right != null){
                popular(local.right, prev, i);
            }
        }
        i++;
        System.out.println(current);
    }
```

Comment: You're printing `current` in a while loop, and never updating it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a tree structure. The easiest way to collect information like what you're asking for is to walk the entire tree (using recursion, not a `while` loop) while passing an object that collects the information. For example, since you want to see which names are the most popular, I'd use a `HashMap` where the keys are the names, and the values are the counts for the name. Then walk the tree however you want (pre-order, post-order, etc.) with the map, incrementing the count for the name at each node.